# How can I easily export a Jira-Zephyr test case with all the steps to Excel?

Tags: jira-zephyr

I defined test cases with several steps for each one.
I have to export the test cases with all the belonging steps to an Excel files.

The possibilities to export a test case, are to Word or XML, but it exports only the JIRA fields (like description, ...) but not the Zephyr fields (like the test steps, test data, test results).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going to the Tests -> Plan Test Cycle.

In the search box provide the ZQL (Zephyr Query Language) to retrieve the test cases you need.

Then click on the Export button and choose the format you need to export this (Excel, CSV etc).

The exported file will show all the test steps, test results etc belonging to the ZQL you have provided.

Comment: If you need to attach test cases without adding the test step then, go to the test plan -> Right click on the test cycle and click on the export cycle